# No libs and no main.dart file in New Flutter Project on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, libs

I'm beginner of programing.

I've already installed Flutter and Dart in my plugins.
I created New Flutter project but I can't find libs file.
How can I solve this problem?

macOS 13.2
Intel Core i5

- I Opened Android Studio.
  Project Structure > Modules
  I removed content entry, and Add Content Root.

Comment: Please share steps of how you created a Flutter App in Android Studio

Comment: can you post a screen shot ?

Comment: hi @dack , 
welcome to https://stackoverflow.com . 
please before ask the question read this guideline. 
(your ask not enough explained the problem , please add screenshots and explain step by step !) so 
you will receive fewer responses. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't create a flutter project. you created an android studio default project.

Create flutter project - `File > New > New Flutter Project`

**If you didn't install flutter correctly, Here are the steps to install Flutter after installing Android Studio:**

- Download the Flutter SDK: You can download the latest version of the Flutter SDK from the [official Flutter website](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases).
- Extract the Flutter SDK: Extract the contents of the downloaded ZIP file to a location on your computer.
- Set up your environment variables
- Verify your installation: Open a terminal window and run the command 'flutter doctor' to check that your installation is complete and there are no missing dependencies.
- Install the Flutter plugin in Android Studio: Start Android Studio and go to the plugin marketplace. Search for the Flutter plugin and click the Install button. Restart Android Studio after the installation is complete.
- Create a new Flutter project: Go to `File > New > New Flutter Project` to create a new Flutter project.
  Now, you can find `main.dart` file and lib folder.

---

or

There is macOS install - Flutter documentation - [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos)